# The iTunesArtwork Image: Is this needed every time, or just in Ad-hoc distribution cases?

Tags: iphone

I am not surfe if I really need every time this 512 x 512 Pixel Icon, since I don't plan to use Ad-hoc distribution. If I get it right, Ad-hoc distribution is the case when you make an App that is supposed to go only on a very few company iPhones, and you dont want anyone to get that app. If that's true, I choose the other distribution type where anyone can get the app. Would I need that image in that case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's for AdHoc distribution where people copy the files into iTunes to allow them to be added to their phone. Technically you don't even need it for AdHoc distribution, if it's not present a default image will be shown in iTunes.

However when submitting to the app store you DO need a 512x512 image which will be shown in the store.

Comment: But note that the 512x512 image is uploaded separately from your app bundle when you submit to the app store.

Comment: since "The new iPad"  - necessary size is 1024x1024

Comment: The help is confusing... http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1 says "App icon for the App Store (REQUIRED) - iTunes uses this icon when presenting your app for distribution. These files must be included at the top level of your app bundle and the names of the files must be iTunesArtwork and iTunesArtwork@2x (no filename extension)."

Answer (score 2):

For ad hoc distributions: you can build the 512 x 512 jpeg image into your application as an "iTunesArtwork" resource, and iTunes will display it automatically.

However, there are two important rules to follow:

- the image format has to be jpeg
- the file name has to be "iTunesArtwork" with no file name extension

When submitting an app to the app store, you upload the 512 x 512 image separately and it does not need to be built into the app as a resource...

Comment: Correction: the image can be JPEG or PNG.

Comment: I tried it with a PNG and iTunes did not render it properly. Perhaps it has to be a PNG with certain characteristics...?

Comment: PNG still works. AFAIK Apple never states it has to be a JPEG, PNG or anything else, just "A large version of your app icon /.../ at least 72 DPI and a minimum of 512x512 pixels /.../". HOWEVER, if you upload a JPEG the artwork will automagically have rounded corners, shine effect etc added later on by Apple. When I upload PNG pics, the icon always remain untouched. This is kinda confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Per [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/145-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html):

> The iTunes artwork your testers see should be your application’s icon. This artwork must be a 512 x 512 JPEG or PNG file named iTunesArtwork. Note that the file must not have an extension.

This will be an image your testers will see, but nothing your end-users will get in the final build.